# Integral-Power series complex identity

Tags: complex-analysis

Given the power series: $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n} z^{n}$,
with radius of convergence R,
prove that for r < R 
the following holds:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi } \int_{0}^{2\pi} | f(r e^{i\theta }) |^{2}  d \theta = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }|a_{n}|^{2} r^{2n}$$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match MSE quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/373780/edit) the question. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Comment: @AntonioVargas, is this comment an outcome of the recent discussion on meta? Is this nw the official policy for questions showing little effort?

Comment: @RichardNash I am not an official, and I don't believe it's official policy, but it is indeed my policy.

Comment: @RichardNash, what Antonio wrote has been the official *unwritten* policy of the site, or more accurately: of most long terms users and  officials. Please do note Antonio wrote "it **may** attract downvotes or be closed", not that if will be *for sure*.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think what Antonio wrote closely resembles an answer on meta. :)

Comment: @RichardNash, right, I copied the comment template from there.  It's much more eloquent than I could hope to be `:)`

Comment: Most probably, @RichardNash . In fact, I find that a very compelling, decent and useful piece of advice for new posters here.

Comment: Here is [same problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221290/how-to-deal-with-fz2-under-integral/221306#221306). Do not forget to up vote this answer if you benefit of it or any other answer.