# Compute $\int _0 ^{2\pi} (\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\cos(nx)}{2^n})^2 dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> **Question:**
>   Compute $$\int _0 ^{2\pi} \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\cos(nx)}{2^n}\right)^2 dx$$

**Thoughts:**
Tried interchanging the integral and the sum, but then the integral turned out to be zero...

Comment: You can't interchange because of the the squared.  (Even without, you may not be able to interchange.)

Comment: Follow this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606043/parsevals-identity-integral/606046#606046).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
write the squared sum as a double sum.
$$ \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\right)^2=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_m\right)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_ma_n.$$

Comment: Note that if you perform the series first, its closed form is $Re\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{\exp\mathrm{i}x}2\right)^n=\frac{2\cos x-1}{5-4\cos x}$ and you get $\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\frac{2\cos x-1}{5-4\cos x}\right)^2\mathrm{d}x=\pi/3$.

Comment: We solved it using the first hint - but now I cant seem to understand how you made the first transition in your comment (to the fraction with 2cosx-1)

Comment: You have $\cos nx=Re(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}nx})$ and then $\frac{\cos nx}{2^n}=Re\left[\left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}/2\right)^n\right]$. The series is performed thanks to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n=\frac{z}{1-z}$ if $|z|<1$. Using $z=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}/2$ and taking the real part you find the expression I have given.