# How to compute $\int_{-\pi}^\pi\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(nx)}{2^n}\bigg)^2dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

> I am trying to compute: 
>   $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(nx)}{2^n}\bigg)^2dx$$

I tired to expand the integrand but it is too messy and lengthy.The Thing is I'm not sure how to deal with the square.  If anyone has an idea on how to compute I will appreciate.

Comment: The [Changing integral and summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081812/changing-integral-and-summation) and [Compute $\int _0 ^{2\pi} (\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\cos(nx)}{2^n})^2 dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613787/compute-int-0-2-pi-sum-n-1-infty-frac-cosnx2n2-dx) could give you some idea.

Comment: That's the same as asking *how to compute $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\pi}{4^n}$*. Do you realize why?

Comment: yes i understand from thé hint below

Comment: The answers at that link are not the best ones IMO.

Comment: @zhw.: maybe true, but we should mention that the OP asked almost the same thing (in disguise) [in his previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512941/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-compute-int-pi-0-bigl-frac-sinx5-4-cosx) and got nice answers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The functions $\cos (nx)$ are orthogonal in $L^2[-\pi,\pi].$