# Prove Parseval Identity for $f \in C(\Bbb T) 2\pi$ periodic continuous functions

Tags: calculus, fourier-series, periodic-functions

**Question:**
Prove Parseval Identity for $f \in C(\Bbb T) $
$2\pi$ periodic continuous functions

$$ \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(x)|^2 dx =\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |\hat f(n)|^2 $$

**Thoughts**:

We are somehow supposed to use the fact that exists $g\in C^1(\Bbb T)$ s.t. $f$ and $g$ are very close. Tried defining a function $h=f-g$, and then the identity is true for the $g$ part but not for the $f$ part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how,

$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(n)e^{inx}\right|^{2}dx = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(n)\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\overline {\hat{f}(m)} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i(n-m)x}dx .$$

Now, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605230/integral-of-series-with-complex-exponentials/605247#605247) for details and how to finish the problem.

**Note:**

> $$ \left|\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(n)e^{inx}\right|^{2}= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(n)e^{ix}\overline {\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} {\hat{f}(m)}e^{ix}}.  $$

Comment: Hi. In the first step, did you mean the sum from -infty to infty? and also, why are you allowed to interchange the sum and the integral?

Comment: @user: Yes, it is a typo.

Comment: and the second question?

Comment: and also - I don't really understand where you start from. Do you start from the right side of the original equation? And if so- why are you allowed to replace f(x) with the sum?

Comment: @user: because your function admits Fourier series  expansion.

Comment: what do you mean by admits?

Comment: It has a Fourier ....

Comment: Do you mean that for each function that has a fourier series we are allowed to assume they're equal and replace them with each other?

Comment: We've studied that for a continuous function, we can assume that the fourier series converges to the function only if it converges uniformly. But here we don't know that it converges uniformly.. (or do we?)

Answer (score 1):

1. Do the computation when $f$ has the form 
   $$\sum_{k=-n}^na_ke^{ikx}, n\in\mathbb N, a_k\in\mathbb R.$$
2. Use density in $C(\mathbb T)$ of such functions.

Comment: are you saying in 1 that every contiunuous periodic function can be described as what you wrote?

Comment: Not exactly: a continuous $2\pi$-periodic function can be approximated by such functions, but for example $\sum_n 2^{—n}\sin(2^nx)$ is not of this form.

Comment: are you saying that the fourier series of f is so close to f (in this case) that we can just interchange them?