# Evaluate the series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n + 1)^6}$ by examining the real Fourier series of the function $f(x) := x(\pi - |x|)$

Tags: fourier-series

The following is a question from a past exam in my university in a course called "Mathematical Methods for Statistics". It consists of two subquestions that may or may not be related (there is a high chance they are related based on similar exams by the same professor).

(a) Write the Fourier series for the function $f(x) := x(\pi - |x|)$ in the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$.

(b) Calculate the sum of the following series:
$$
S :=\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n + 1)^6}
$$

---

***Attempted solution***

(a)
$$
f(x) \sim \frac{8}{\pi} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{\sin((2n + 1) x)}{(2n + 1)^3}
$$

(b) Based on past exams, I expect the result to follow from part (a) by evaluating $f(x)$ at some appropriately chosen $x$, but I can't figure out what this $x$ might be. The best I got was by assigning $x := \frac{\pi}{2}$, which yields:
$$
f(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{(2n + 1)^3}
$$

If we define $a_n := \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n + 1)^3}$, we have that $S = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n^2$. But how do I proceed from here?

Another possibility is that my answer to part (a) is wrong.

Comment: You have $(2n+1)^{-3}$. You want $(2n+1)^{-6}$. How do you get from the first to the second. Which theorem is related to that operation in the context of Fourier analysis?

Comment: @DanielFischer: the Parseval identity?

Comment: Exactly that one.

Comment: [Here] is [Parseval identity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617918/prove-parseval-identity-for-f-in-c-bbb-t-2-pi-periodic-continuous-functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer)'s help, and assuming correctness of my answer to part (a), here's my answer to part (b).

By Parseval's identity,

$$
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x^2 (\pi - |x|)^2 dx = \frac{64}{\pi^2}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n + 1)^6}
$$

Whence

$$
S = \frac{\pi^6}{960}
$$