# Let $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is an univalent function , and $f(0)=0,f'(0)=1$ , find the minimum of the area.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is an univalent function , and $f(0)=0,f'(0)=1$ , find the minimum of the area.

My idea: I want to use the surface element as we know $dzd\bar{z}=d(x+iy)d(x-iy)=-2idxdy$ and use the mean value principle，but I can't put it all together and I don't know if it's true.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: My personal strong suspicion (with no actual argument to back it up): $f(x) = x$ gives the minimum area. Just to be clear: $\Bbb D$ is the unit disc, right?

Comment: @Arthur: Your suspicion is correct (only that I never would use $x$ for a complex variable :)

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, should've said $f(n) = n$ ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can express the area of the image in terms of the Taylor coefficients of the function, compare [Let $f$ be an analytic isomorphism on the unit disc $D$, find the area of $f(D)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764827/let-f-be-an-analytic-isomorphism-on-the-unit-disc-d-find-the-area-of-fd). Therefore

$$
 \text{area}\, f(D) = \pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \lvert a_{n} \rvert^2
\ge \pi |a_1| = \pi |f'(0)|  = \pi
$$

and equality holds if $f$ is linear, i.e. for $f(z) = z$.